# How to unstick my light switch?

Tags: switch, light-fixture

I was messing around trying to change a light fixture and the circuit breaker for the house tripped open. I reset the circuit breaker, fixed it correctly and everything else is working. But the light switch will not turn off now. It just springs constantly to the on position and there is no click when manually you hold the switch into the off position. I assume it is stuck, is this a job for a total novice when it comes to these things? Any easy answers?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'the house fused'.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo The knobs in the fuse box switched off. The knob for that light and the knob for the main electricity

Comment: Ok, so you were working on electrical appliances while the power was on.  I trust you won't be repeating that mistake...

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo ha ha, no, i turned on the light to see if was fixed and whilst turning it on the house fused and swith got stuck

Comment: Well that's good to know at least.

Comment: Can you give us the step-by-step of what you did and what happened? Eg, 1. You turned off the power to this branch circuit,  2. Replaced the light fixture  3. Turned on circuit, 4....   It's very unclear if you were working on something while the power was live, and if the light switch broke at the same instance the breaker tripped, and I'm unclear if the main house breaker tripped (cutting power to the entire house) or just this circuit.  Also not clear what "messing around" means - did you just replace the light fixture or did you change the way it's wired or change any wiring at the switch?

Comment: You're also saying things like "the circuit breaker .. tripped open" and then saying "the knobs in the fuse box". Do you have [circuit breakers](http://0.tqn.com/d/homerepair/1/0/N/B/-/-/cktbrkrpnl_notes.jpg) or [fuses](http://0.tqn.com/d/homerepair/1/0/P/B/-/-/fusepanel_notes.jpg)? If you have a fuse box, I'm guessing by "knobs" you actually mean "fuses" but as I said, it's very unclear. Take pictures if you need and point arrows to what tripped and what you did, otherwise it's very difficult to help you because we're not speaking the same language. :)

Comment: Messing with a light fixture should not trip a breaker unless either the switch was on (regardless of the toggle position) or the circuit was mis-wired -- switched neutral instead of switched hot. Definitely replace the switch, but ensure the circuit is correctly wired as well. Sounds like the switch may have been defective before any of this even started. And one more reason to always kill the power at the breaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The switch was probably damaged by a short circuit caused by wiring your fixture incorrectly.

So - how do you fix?

Step 1:  Turn off the fuse/breaker that was blown/tripped when you caused the short

Step 2:  Remove the face plate for the broken switch

Step 3:  Remove the screws that anchor the switch in the electrical box.  Do not remove any wires.

Step 4:  Study the switch and make careful note of where each wire connects.  The old switch *should* have markings on it that indicate things like "hot", "neutral" and "ground".  Take some sticky labels like mailing labels and write down each connection on a label and stick that label on the wire before you remove it from the switch.

Step 5:  After you've labelled all the wires and removed the switch, take it to your local hardware store and buy a replacement.

Step 6:  Come home and reconnect the wires exactly as they were before.

Step 7:  Mount the switch in the box.  Replace the face plate.  Turn on the power in the fuse/breaker box.

Comment: no, i turned on the light to see if was fixed and whilst turning it on the house fused and swith got stuck

Comment: Step 0: If you don't know the proper safety procedures, hire an electrician.

Comment: +1 I would add *Check every wire in the box with a non-contact tester*, as a standard precaution for almost all electric work. I realize this is asking a bit from the casual DIYer, but despite years of electric work, I have hit an unchecked live wire and fried a screwdriver, switch, but fortunately, not myself.

Comment: @BMitch what did i do wrong, see http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/how-to-unstick-my-light-switch#comment25647_18275

Comment: Can't tell what you did wrong on the installation w/o more info.  That's a different question.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo i was talking about that fact that i wasnt working on it with a live wire. Is your answer easy to implement?

Comment: I think its fairly easy but I can't speak for your skill level.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo skill level of 0

Comment: Not terribly difficult as long as you pay careful attention to the wiring as stated in the answer.  Switches are designed to be easily replaced.